# Return column in separate row in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my `Customers` table, I have `PrimaryPhone` and `SecondaryPhone` columns and I'm asked to return them in two separate rows. I also want to mention that in most cases, `SecondaryPhone` may not even have a value and in those cases, there's no need to return the second row.

So, here's the data coming from `Customers` table:

```
CustomerId  |  CompanyName      |  PrimaryPhone    |  SecondaryPhone
123            Acme, Inc.          307-555-1234       307-555-2345
234            DataCorp, Inc.   |  824-555-6547
```

My `SELECT` statement should return the following data:

```
CustomerId  | CompanyName     | Phone
123           Acme, Inc.        307-555-1234
123           Acme, Inc.        307-555-2345
234           DataCorp, Inc.    824-555-6547
```

I'd appreciate some pointers on how to show data from a column as a separate row. Thanks.

Comment: Can there exists rows where `Primary` is null but `secundary`is not null ?

Comment: @GuidoG, Yes, that's possible, thought it shouldn't happen. No data is always 100% clean so it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CROSS APPLY would be a good fit here

```
Select CustomerId
      ,CompanyName
      ,B.*
 From Customers A
 Cross Apply (values (PrimaryPhone)
                    ,(SecondaryPhone)
             ) B(Phone)
  Where Phone is not null
```

-- EDIT forgot the WHERE

Comment: Will this not return a second row if there's no secondary phone number?

Comment: I see your EDIT. Thank you!

Comment: @Sam Happy to help  :)

Comment: What if `Primary`is null and `Secondary` is not ?

Comment: @GuidoG No issue.  Then only the secondary phone would be be returned.

Answer (score 3):

You could try an union like this

```
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    CompanyName,
    PrimaryPhone as Phone,
FROM dbo.Customers
UNION 
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    CompanyName,
    SecondaryPhone as Phone,
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE 
    SecondaryPhone IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` would probably have a speed benefit here.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @StefanCrain The other answer also does not includes an explanation, so why do you only comment that for this answer ? Dont get me wrong, I actually agree on this

Comment: @GuidoG To help a new contributor provide the most value to our community. The question specifically asks for pointers, a code only response is just a solution and doesn't help others learn about the reasoning behind these solutions.

Comment: @StefanCrain In that case you should put the same remark with the other answer. It also has no pointers, and it is also code only. Why only here, that is my question

Comment: @GuidoG I don’t have to comment on every answer on SO to make a difference in the quality of answers. I’m not a moderator. I choose to focus my attention on people that are new and haven’t contributed before. If you feel strongly about lack of consistency maybe you can add a comment?

Comment: @StefanCrain So you are saying that anyone with enough reputation can write an answer without explanation, but anyone with no reputation cannot ? Is that your criteria ? It does not matter that much to me, I am just curious

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191097/discussion-between-stefan-crain-and-guidog).

Answer (score 0):

This is Perfect way(Query) to solve Your Problem

```
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    CompanyName,
    PrimaryPhone as Phone
FROM dbo.Customer
UNION  
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    CompanyName,
    SecondaryPhone as Phone
FROM dbo.Customer
WHERE 
  DATALENGTH(SecondaryPhone)<>0
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: How does this differs from HappyPengin's answer ?

Comment: DataLength is the best way solve to Check value null or not and it also remove your blank Space...

Thank You!!!